# Can I have Angular2 and .NET Web Api in a single project?

Tags: angular, .net-core

I going to start new solution in Visual Studio Code and I need to ask you about project/solution organization. My intention is to have client side built on Angular2 and server side services provided by .NET Core Web Api.

Can I create one single project in VS Code containing items for both that technologies (Anglular2 and Web Api) ?  Or I should have two different projects in my solution, one for Angular2 and another to Web Api ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use visual studio code for .net web api and angular cli for angular project. it will make your life much much easier.

Comment: I saw that its possible to develop Angular2 from VS code as well. Isn't it true ?

Comment: yes, of course. you can then use VS code (or VS) to develop angular project. its just a matter of how to organize solution. my recommendation is to keep them completely separated. so, have .net web api as one solution in vs code. have angular project managed by angular cli (and use vs code to work on angular one, also).

Comment: you might find this topic useful also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684179/add-angular-4-to-an-asp-netcore-project/44684239#44684239

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great post https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa that explains how to setup angular2 project from scratch and the .net webapi project at one place. Everything can be done in Visual Studio 2017!

Answer (score 0):

I just played with Visual Studio ASP.NET Core with Angular (using dotnet new angular). It seems very nice at first glance.
But the generated project does not use Angular 4.3.2 but 4.1.2.
Ok, it is easy to update the version. However I am wondering if I should not use angular-cli anyway because of its regularly updates. 
I am worried that the dotnet cli is not going to be updated regularly.
I would like to have also feedback of people who tried both solutions.
Thanks

Comment: you can post your doubt as question.not answer

Comment: Dotnet cli update has nothing to do with angular-cli